# Can you deep link into a page from a controller in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, deeplink

I have some tabs within a view in an MVC page and sometimes I'd like to be able to link directly to one particular tab from the controller. I'm using a javascript framework for the tabs called EasyTabs which accomplishes the tab nagivation by appending #tabname to the end of the url. Right now I'm returning the view like so

```
return View("EditDealer", repo.GetEditDealerViewModel(custId));
```

Is there any way I could get the routing engine to append my #tabname to the end of the url that gets generated? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by returning something in the model, and have this in the view:

```
<script>
window.location.hash='@Model.tabname'
</script>
```

Comment: D'oh! I guess it's true what they say, the simplest solutions are the best ones! Much appreciated.